# Are some blueprints' "random bonus" limited to a subset?

Tags: the-division

I recently purchased the item level 32 Stamina and Firearms Gear Mod blueprints and crafted four of one and three of the other. All seven were Prototypes and had either Skill Haste or Exotic Damage Resistance for their random bonus, but I really need Armor.

I've gotten several Advanced versions as drops in the DZ with Armor and other bonuses, but I don't recall picking up any Prototypes with Armor. I don't want to keep wasting materials if getting Armor on these Prototypes is impossible.

Is each level of item (Advanced vs. Prototype) restricted in the possible secondary random bonuses they can have? Is there a list compiled from anecdotal evidence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used these blueprints and crafted plenty of Stamina, Firearms and Electronics ilvl 32 Gear Mods. I did get many with armor, but I did get a lot with crappy bonuses as you mention. Most I got was 160 armor IIRC. So it's most definitely possible, but it's not easy. You have to craft a lot to get what you want.

However, it seems that The Division's *"randomness"* isn't truly random, as instead it's time based (it has been [confirmed by the community for loot](https://www.reddit.com/r/thedivision/comments/4nkh0c/confirmed_confirmed_the_rng_for_opening_sealed/), and rumored for crafting). If you don't get what you need with first few tries you should try some other time.

As far as I know, *Advanced* vs *Prototype* just denotes the level.

Comment: in computers, you can not simply call a random number. Technically, computers have no understanding of random. There are many ways to disguise this, and have seemingly random numbers, and the main way Ive been taught is by using the system clock. The reddit article itself actually details "random" as it can be implemented in this way, and only seems to argue that it is implemented poorly.

Comment: @Timelord64: I'm perfectly aware how PRNG works. The way it works in The Division is _not_ standard PRNG.

Comment: maybe so, but the only evidence to that in the article you reference is a bunch of users trying to speculate on developers intent, and regardless, the example given *is a common flaw in poor random script*, and is completely irrelevant to crafting.

Comment: @Timelord64: it's the same game using same "random" generator. The fact that getting loot at _same_ time yields _same_ loot has been *confirmed*.  The fact that crafting comes in anomalous streaks of same bonuses/talents has been reported by multiple well respected members of community. I have experienced that myself. As has the OP. No amount of hairsplitting will change the fact, that RNG in The Division is flawed.

Comment: @Timelord64 Why the -1 (if that's yours)? This answer provides anecdotal evidence that it is possible to get Armor while crafting an ilvl 32 Prototype Stamina or Firearms Gear Mod. The PRNG weirdness is a sideline issue, but my question is indeed answered.

Comment: @DavidHarkness, despite what vartec alledges, there is no "broken random" in crafting, as it is listed for chest drops. I have personally crafted "in bulk", before. Even when they reduced the crafting time, there is a very obvious level of random in what generates. I have pointed out that the reference atm is just speculation and an un-recreatable exploit (you can not craft two items at the same time), but vartec insists that the reference is reliable. I am not convinced. Ultimately, this makes this answer unuseful, to me.